# Как изменить цвет кнопки в Office365 ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365

Столкнулся с банальной проблемой. При работе с bootstrap используются известные классы primary,info,warning для создания кнопки определенного цвета. В `offcie365 fabric` для ReactJS есть  [компоненты](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/button) `DefaultButton, PrimaryButton, CompoundButton` и все. Причем есть раздел,посвященный [цветам](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/styles/colors). Но я не понимаю, как задать кнопке цвет. пробовал 
`<DefaultButton className = 'neutralDark' onClick={ onClose } text='Lost & Found' />`  не работает. Как можно поменять цвет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать именование классов, как написано в документации `ms-bgColor-themePrimary`. В вашем случае должно получиться так:

```
<DefaultButton
  className='ms-bgColor-neutralDark'
  onClick={ onClose }
  text='Lost & Found'
/>
```

Comment: Это тоже пробовал. Он добавляет этот класс к "root_61661014  ms-Button ms-Button--default root_ff4910b2 isEnabled_ff4910b2", получается 
root_61661014 ms-bgColor-neutralDark ms-Button ms-Button--default root_ff4910b2 isEnabled_ff4910b2, но ничего не меняется default-класс похоже,перекрывает его

Comment: А вы добавили ссылку на css для поддержки этих классов? `https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/4.1.0/css/fabric.min.css`

ссылка: https://dev.office.com/fabric#core

Comment: Вот пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/73N8xo5wr  в index.html добавлен css, классы меняет нормально.